# Assign RDS to a VPC using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I am creating an RDS using

> create-db-instance

How do I assign it to VPC group? I don't see any tag to achieve that. It is picking default VPC group and assigning to the RDS.

Here is the script I am using to create the RDS (I am passing variable in the tags which are defined in the bash script).>>

```
aws rds create-db-instance \
--db-name WIND \
--vpc-security-group-ids $sgGroup_id \
--db-instance-identifier $Instance_Identifier \
--allocated-storage 100 \
--copy-tags-to-snapshot \
--db-instance-class ${arrDbClass[$iDbClass]} \
--engine oracle-ee \
--engine-version ${arrEngVer[$iEngVer]} \
--license-model bring-your-own-license \
--master-username oraadmin \
--master-user-password $oraadminPassword \
--no-auto-minor-version-upgrade \
--no-publicly-accessible \
--backup-retention-period $backup_Retention_Period \
--no-storage-encrypted \
--storage-type gp2 \
--no-enable-iam-database-authentication \
  $multi_Az \
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `--db-subnet-group-name` to point to a [DBSubnetGroup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_DBSubnetGroup.html), which contains a list of subnets where the database is permitted to launch.

The subnets belong to a VPC.

Therefore, the order is:

- Create a DBSubnetGroup pointing to subnets in your VPC
- Launch the RDS Instance into the DBSubnetGroup

Comment: Got it, thanks. Any suggestion how I can list all DBSubnetGroups name only?

Comment: This is working..>

aws rds describe-db-subnet-groups --query DBSubnetGroups[*].DBSubnetGroupName --output table